# How to use Ansible with_fileglob template to exclude some files?

Tags: ansible

I have one block of Ansible, using `with_fileglob`.

How can i exclude files with name containing `useless`?

```
- set_fact: files:{{item}}
  with_fileglob:
    - "path/to/*.tar.gz | exclude "useless"
```

In another word, I don't want to get the file name with such string "useless".

How could I realize it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a nice oneliner for you:

```
- set_fact:
    files: "{{ lookup('fileglob','path/to/*.tar.gz',wantlist=true) | reject('search','useless') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `glob` allows include patterns; it allows excluding some characters only, but not for substrings.
You could try excluding files containing "useless" with two steps as below, although it gets a `register` and not a `fact`

```
   - name: retrieve list of files
     command: ls {{ item }}
     register: contents
     with_fileglob:
       - path/to/*.tar.gz

   - name: list excluding useless
     debug: msg="Useful file {{item.item}}"
     with_items: "{{ contents.results }}"
     when: "{{ item.stdout.find('useless')}} == -1"
```